# Angular iterate object of arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, ngfor

TYPESCRIPT:

```
this.paises = this.api.getAllCountries();

        this.paises.forEach(item => {
            this.paisesData.push(item);
        });
```

ANGULAR:

```
 <ion-item button detail lines="inset" *ngFor="let pais of paisesData" (click)="paisesInfo(pais)">
            {{ pais.response }}
        </ion-item>
```

OBJECT OF ARRAYS:

[image: How to list in its owns button every country that is inside response array?]

QUESTION:

How to list in its owns button every country that is inside **response** array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put another loop

```
<ion-item button detail lines="inset" *ngFor="let pais of paisesData" (click)="paisesInfo(pais)">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let country of pais.response">{{ country }}</li>
  </ul>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Insert response data into the array and avoid multiple loops on template.

```
this.paises = this.api.getAllCountries();

    this.paises.forEach(item => {
        this.paisesData.push(item.response);
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <ion-item button detail lines="inset" *ngFor="let pais of paisesData" (click)="paisesInfo(pais)">
        {{ pais }}
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: I need the inner loop as sugested in previous answer because without it i'm not able to create separate buttons for every key.